# Sum of unnamed column in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hcatalog, bigdata

```
 shipnode,delivery_method ,<unnamed>
 (9935,PICK,2)
 (9960,PICK,2)
 (9969,PICK,1)
 (9963,SHP,1)
 (9989,SHP,1)
 (9995,SHP,1)
 (9965,SHP,1)
 (9995,SHP,1)
```

this is the output  of

```
 grunt> group_all_shipnode = GROUP
 >> union_all 
 >> BY(
 >> shipnode,delivery_method
 >> )
 >> ;
```

the last column is unnamed , now i want to generate 
as the grouping by shipnode and delivery_node and taking sum of the third column as

```
 (9935,PICK,2)
 (9960,PICK,2)
 (9969,PICK,1)
 (9963,SHP,1)
 (9989,SHP,1)
 (9995,SHP,2) <<-------      sum of similar 
 (9965,SHP,1)
```

i am trying by this :

```
 grunt> sum_group_all_shipnode =FOREACH group_all_shipnode 
 >> GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as(shipnode:chararray, delivery_method:chararray),
 >> sum($1.$2);
```

which produce error:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1070: Could not resolve sum using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Comment: Doesn't the "Could not resolve sum using import" indicate, that the symbol `sum` cannot be resolved?

Comment: ya but what is the way to sum it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $1.$2 it needs to be the relation from your load statement.
For example assuming you are loading the data to a relation A.

```
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING PigStorage(',');
group_all_shipnode = GROUP A BY ($1,$2);
sum_group_all_shipnode = FOREACH group_all_shipnode 
                         GENERATE 
                             FLATTEN(group) AS (shipnode:chararray, delivery_method:chararray),
                             SUM(A.$2);
```

Comment: @VishalVerma SUM needs to be in capital.Do you have SUM in small letters?

Comment: problem solved i used SUM($1.$2) may be i wrote sum earlier . nyways thnks  :)